# How do I get the element with the smallest key in a collection, in O(1) or O(log n) time?

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures, big-o

I know that I can use a `Dictionary` and retrieve an arbitrary element in O(1) time.

I know that I can get the next highest (or lowest) element in a [**`SortedDictionary`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) in O(1) time.  But what if I wanted to remove the **first** value (based on `TKey`'s `IComparable`) in the `SortedDictionary`?

Can I use the [**`.First()`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) method  to retrieve the smallest key?  And what is its complexity?  Will it run in O(1), O(log n) or O(n) time?

Is the `SortedDictionary` the correct data structure for this?

Note: The use case is sort of a poor man's priority queue or ordered queue.  No open-source is allowed for this (must be code-from-scratch, or already in the .NET 3.5 framework).

Comment: Robert, in a sorted dictionary you need usually log2n to get min element, it's not O(1). Heaps offer O(1) access to min(or max).

Comment: @best: I didn't say `min` is O(1).  Read the question again: The *next* element is O(1)

Comment: next *highest/lowest* (in a subset), predecessor/successor of an element are also not O(1).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SortedList and SortedDictionary are implemented internally as binary search trees and could ideally give you O(log n) performance for a Min (requires walking the tree, but not enumerating the whole list). However, using LINQ to perform that Min will probably enumerate the entire list.

I would consider a [Skip List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379573%28v=vs.80%29.aspx#datastructures20_4_topic4) as a better alternative data structure.

Comment: Does .NET have a native skip list implementation?

Comment: @Robert, sadly no - you would have to implement it yourself (or use an open source implementation, but you said that's not an option.) However, the basic algorithm isn't especially difficult to implement and the MSDN article I linked walks you through the core.

Comment: LINQ would use `GetEnumerator()` to fetch the first element (O(log n)), not `Min()`.

Comment: @Marcelo, whether .First() (aka: GetEnumerator) would return the minimum value depends on the sort order of the SortedList<T>. So it may or may not satisfy the requirement. The OP's question was a little fuzzy.

Comment: Min requires enumerating the whole list because it can't know it's sorted. LINQ does have a .First() method.

Comment: The only thing that bothers me about Skip Lists would be their memory consumption. Too huge..

Comment: @nawfal Skip List worst case space is O(n log n), but expected case (balanced) is O(n). Trading memory for speed is often an acceptable option. However, as with all data structures it will not be the ideal choice for every possible scenario.

Comment: @hemp I get your point, it's about cost benefit analysis and sometimes skip lists make the cut. What I mean is I dont jump on the "faster-the better" bandwagon when I know it has a cost. What makes me give a double thinking before I use it is the fact it consumes a lot of memory per entry, so I know it might have a limit to how much it can hold. It's not only about scaling, but also how much it practically can hold without being too much on memory. In a skip list every entry holds an array of other node references, the biggest difference maker.

Comment: SortedList doesn't use a BST behind the scenes. It's just a sorted array which uses Binary Search for lookups.

Comment: @dev27 you're correct, I'm not sure why I thought both structures used BSTs. The time to remove records in the two structures varies significantly. In case of the OP's question, SortedList's RemoveAt function requires two full array copies, which is definitely not great.

Answer (score 5):

[SortedDictionary.GetEnumerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1z8z05h2.aspx) is stated as having O(log n) time - so First() should follow suit.

Comment: @hemp: Isn't that what the `SortedDictionary` does?

Comment: @Robert: It sorts by using IComparable - how that IComparable is implemented determines the sort order. Since you own the data structure in this case, it would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `SortedDictionary` or `SortedList`, you can use `.First()` (or `dict.Keys[0]` for `SortedList`) Otherwise, you could do:

```
dict[dict.Keys.Min()]
```

which would have overall O(N) time (as Min() must iterate the whole collection)

`.First()` will probably have O(1) time for a SortedList and O(log n) for SortedDictionary.

Insertion and Removal will be O(log N) time for SortedDictionary and may be up to O(N) for SortedList. Note that if you're using a dictionary to back your "priority queue" you can't have two items with the same priority.

I don't think either class has a special implementation for Last, so if you want the highest valued key, you should probably use a SortedList since you can do `dict.Keys[dict.Count-1]`. If you want *only* the highest (and not the lowest), you could use a Comparer to sort it in that order and use First.

Comment: I think the goal would be to get O(log n) or better. There will be a lot of items in the collection, and they will always be retrieved smallest key first.

Comment: Then you should use a `SortedDictionary` (or `SortedList`). Just keep your insertion and removal costs in mind too.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you keep a separate sorted list of the keys so that you can always get the element with the smallest key just by doing `dict[keyList[0]]`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you only mentioned getting values and not setting them,
You could use a simple list, sort it in advance, then access any value, by order, in O(1).

Answer (score -1):

With an unsorted collection, getting the highest or lowest element is O(n) because any of the items could be the highest or lowest so you have to look at each.  If you want to do this quickly (O(1)) you need a sorted data structure so you can infer the relative positions of values based on their location.